# Changing image in Window Application (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Goal: Changing an image to another one when a red button is clicked.
But there is a problem when changing initial panda image to animation character image.
panda image is set up in the mainpage.xaml.

```
<Page
x:Class="App3.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App3"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Button Height="100" Width="100" Click="Button_Click" Background="#FFEA2323"/>
    <Image x:Name="image" Source="Images/panda1.png"  Margin="436,170,418,174"/>

</Grid>
</Page>
```

And character image is set up when button is clicked
This is "mainpage.xaml.cs" code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes;
using Windows.UI;
using System.Windows;

// 빈 페이지 항목 템플릿에 대한 설명은 http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=234238 에 나와 있습니다.

namespace App3
{
/// <summary>
/// 자체에서 사용하거나 프레임 내에서 탐색할 수 있는 빈 페이지입니다.
/// </summary>
/// 

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\Users\hinon\OneDrive\Documents\2016-2\04. 놀이방\03. 키넥트 제스처 기반 게임 제작 환경 구성\03. 데이터베이스\01. 이미지\닥터슬럼프 아리.bmp", UriKind.Absolute));
        //BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
        //bitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri(@"C:\Users\hinon\OneDrive\Documents\2016-2\04. 놀이방\03. 키넥트 제스처 기반 게임 제작 환경 구성\03. 데이터베이스\01. 이미지\닥터슬럼프 아리.bmp", UriKind.Absolute);
        //image.Source = bitmapImage;

    }
}
}
```

But it is not successful. If I click the button, initial panda image is dissapeared, and no image opend. just black. What I missed in this code?

[Before click the red button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Bxf4.png)
[After click the red button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gc4Tl.png)

Comment: Provided that the image file path is correct, your code should work.

Comment: Really the matter is only path??